# my html file returns blank page. How to solve this?

Tags: python, html, django

my file temp.py read data from my sensor connected to my rasbperry . my views sends it to html file . I think my call in index.html is not correct . Because when I run my Django project it returns a blank page

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from temp import get_temp
import json 
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'aps/index.html', {'t' : get_temp()})
```

temp.py

```
def get_temp() :

tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000075292ed/w1_slave")
text = tfile.read()
tfile.close()
secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
temperature  = float(temperaturedata[2:])
temperature = temperature / 1000
return temperature
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title> Temperature Sensor</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = {{ t }} ;
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live sensor temperature data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'sensor data',
                data: (function () {
                  
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: {{ t }}
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]
        });
    });
});
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check the urls.py file and the configuration file?

Comment: did you check the javascript console for errors?

Comment: My urls.py  and settings.py have no problem because I run the graph before adding the temp.py and it was working normally

Answer (score 0):

Add your urls.py

What url are you using at the browser?

If possible add what give you back the browser when you press cntrl+u  in your blank page.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. To request clarification, please post a comment on the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I tried that before post, but apparently I do not have the level to comment. Just trying to help...

Comment: @QUHO that's okay. We've all been there. Here, take my upvote.

Comment: I run this html file befoore adding temp.py I mean with random data and it shows a graph but now nomore  . when I pressed ctrl+u my yAxis receive the correct data .